# Git local branch out of date, but nothing to pull?

Tags: git, github, push, git-branch, pull

I have a problem with git branch called nightly in my repo. When I was trying to `git push` to branch I got an error:

```
 ! [rejected]        nightly -> nightly (non-fast-forward)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Martin819/quoll.git'
 hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
 hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
 hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have already run into this problem several times, so I thought the solution is straight forward. I had to `git pull`.

But, when I tries to `git pull` it says:

```
 * branch            nightly    -> FETCH_HEAD
 Already up to date.
```

So I tried to check the status with `git remote show origin` and got:

```
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master    tracked
    nightly   tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master  merges with remote master
    nightly merges with remote nightly
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master    pushes to master    (up to date)
    nightly   pushes to nightly   (local out of date)
```

I'm now confused, because there it says that local branch is out of date, but when trying to pull it says Already up to date. Anyway how to solce this?

Comment: What does `git status` on your `nightly` branch say?

Comment: It says 
`On branch nigthly`
`nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: So, you don't have any changes in your local branch is it? Or are there some untracked/uncommitted files?

Comment: I do, but I have already created commit which contains all local changes. Now I'm unable to push them.

Comment: If you have committed then it should say `your branch is ahead of origin/nightly by 1 commit`. What is the commit name btw? `git pull origin nightly`?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have tried to `git reset HEAD~1`, `git status` to check there are like 10 files changed, then `git add -A`, `git commit -m "<some message>"` and then `git status` and it again says `working tree clean`...I don't understand it.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi I have solved my problem (See the answer). Thank you for your time spend on this issue. Have a nice day.

Comment: You can also implement a Github action to automatically rebase your PRs. This is the one I have tried before: https://github.com/cirrus-actions/rebase
Alternatively, there are some Github apps available to automate the rebasing and merging as well. One I've used in past is called https://mergequeue.com that does both rebasing and merging. That avoids these kind of situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. I have accidently checkouted to 'nigthly' branch instead of 'nightly' creating a new local branch, which caused this problem. After chechout to the branch the problem disappeared.